# JDeveloper Create Web Service

Tags: oracle, web-services, weblogic, jdeveloper, soa-suite

I am following book Getting started with oracle suite 11g R1 A Hands on tutorial.
I am using a bit more recent versions that recommended in book (because there is no place any more where I can download files recommended by book) and till now everything was OK.

Specifically I am using JDeveloper Studio Edition Version 11.1.1.5.0, Build JDEVADF_11.1.1.5.0_GENERIC_110409.0025.6013, SOA Composite Editor 11.1.1.5.0.01.74 and SOA Server PCBPEL_11.1.1.5.0_GENERIC_110418.1550.0174

while in book they suggest JDEVADF_11.1.1.1.0_GENERIC_090615.0017.5407. and SOA Composite Editor: 11.1.1.0.0.52.19 and SOA Server PCBPEL_11.1.1.1.0_GENERIC_090618.1440.5219.

Here comes the problem:
In book they instruct to do this

[image]
[image]

But when I try do do that, i get this (look similar to screenshot from book)

[image]

...and here comes the **big** difference...

[image]

..and especially after I click at magnifying glass...

[image]

After this point whatever I try I can't get to this:

[image]

**Have a missed some step? 
Or if the JDeveloper version are so much different how should I accomplish what they instruct to do? Or a problem is in a SOA suite or it's JDeveloper extension?**

Up to this point all tests were passed, and everything was working as suggested in a book.

- How should I resolve that problem?
- Where could I get files that they advise to be used as Oracle is not offering them anymore for download?

(quotation from book)

> Go to:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/soa/soasuite/index.html, and
>   download the following from SOA Suite 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.1.0) to
>   c:\stageSOA:
>
> WebLogic Server:wls1031_win32.exe
>
> Repository Creation Utility:ofm_rcu_win32_11.1.1.1.0_disk1_1of1.zip
>
> SOA Suite:ofm_soa_generic_11.1.1.1.0_disk1_1of1.zip
>
> JDeveloper Studio, base install: jdevstudio11111install.jar

- Is there ANY tutorial or book which covers the most recent version of SOA Suite 12c altogether with JDeveloper and Database - so in short, updated version of their book? Especially if it covers SoreFrontDemo (or similar) application?

UPDATE: If I click here

[image]

and select that option than I have option to do this:

[image]

..and this...

[image]

and finally this - coud thisbe resolution to this problem?

[image]

UPDATE 2:
I found JDeveloper version jdevstudio11112install.jar and with it screenshots from book matches screen menus from that version of JDeveloper. Still it would be better if i could find version jdevstudio11111install.jar. I had to find and manually install soa-jdev-extension.zip because it is not avaiable with automatic update/install of extesnions (JDeveloper asks for support username and pass).

What I want to ask is how to get to following screens in JDeveloper jdevstudio11115install.jar or jdevstudio11117install.jar or who are still more- less officially supported.

[image]
[image]

If I could get there then I could set those parameters instructed by the book.

Is there ANY place where I could get jdevstudio11111install.jar as well as the following files from SOA Suite 11g Release 1(11.1.1.1.0):

- WebLogic Server: wls1031_win32.exe
- Repository Creation Utility: ofm_rcu_win32_11.1.1.1.0_disk1_1of1.zip
- SOA Suite: ofm_soa_generic_11.1.1.1.0_disk1_1of1.zip
- JDeveloper Studio, base install: jdevstudio11111install.jar

Comment: If I had to guess - check the "copy wsdl and dependent artifacts" checkbox and it will automatically grab the XSDs. They probably automated downloading/fetching the XSDs based on the WSDL so you don't have to do the extra step of importing the schemas anymore. If I am way wrong let me know

Comment: I tried that - nothing happens OK button is still grayed out :( but if I click after that on + to add WSDL then I am offered to select "getCreditValidation.wsdl" which if I chose then fields are autopopulated and I can click OK, but I don't know if that would lead to desired result (see updated question.

Comment: I'm thinking it will work based on your last image/screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( I can't set up required parameters mentioned later in book.

Comment: @castling please have a look at UPDATE2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At this point:...

> and here comes the big difference...

Click the Green + where it says Input - this will lead you to where you can choose the type.
The search-spyglass icon you were clicking on is where to SAVE the WSDL it will generate based on the XSD. You choose the XSD by clicking the Green +.
A GREAT book to learn SOA Suite is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849680183).
Start with that and go through the tutorial at the back - takes you from XSD/WSDL to full SOA Suite impl in a few chapters.